# Samba file share shows user directory

Tags: samba, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I recently set up a Samba file share on Raspian and when I login to it from a Windows, it shows the home directory for the logged in user.

Below is an excerpt from my `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file

```
[Backup]
comment = Backup Folder
path = /media/USBHDD/shares
valid users = @users
force group = users
create mask = 0660
directory mask = 0755
read only = no
```

Below is a screen shot to show what I am experiencing:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Is this common? (I don't want user's home directories to be displayed, just the backups)
2. How can I make it so that the user's home directory is *not* displayed?

Comment: Does your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` have a `[homes] section? If so, that will be the place to disable showing the users' home directories.

Comment: Yes it does. I commented out the `[homes]` section and achieved the desired result. I will answer when I am allowed to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/etc/samba/smb.conf` has a `[homes]` section by default. Either comment this out, or make desired changes to it to prevent it being accessed.